# Появляется белый отступ при мобильный версии сайта

Tags: html, css, media-queries

возник интересный момент, а именно когда при мобильной версии сайта разрешение 768px и выше белого отступа нет.

А вот если разрешение 425px и ниже, а чем ниже разрешение, тем больше белый отступ. 
Прошу помощи в решение проблемы или указания, где и что не так правильно прописываю в @media

Буду очень признателен!

[image: 768px и выше]
[image: 425px и ниже]
[image: Еще один показ]

```css
@media screen  and (min-width: 360px) {

        html, body {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .b1 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: url(First.jpg) repeat;
    
    }

    .b1 h1 {
        font-size: 60px;
    }
```

```html
<section class="b1">
      <div class="content1">
        <h1>OMG I NEED HELP</h1>
        <a class="btn" href="#Stop" onclick="slowScroll('#Stop')">See more</a>
        <a class="btn" href="contactform.html">Contact with me</a>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: в том коде что вы скинули белому отступу взяться неоткуда. Можете страницу показать?

Comment: @TheDrote вам скриншот полный отправить ? Если да, то могу, а если ссылку дать, то нет, пока нет в инете.

Comment: @TheDrote как смог, прикрепил скриншот фулл-страницы, как она отображается при 425px / 849px

Comment: от скриншота никакого толку совершенно, нужно смотреть код. У вас у какого то блока нверное стоит min-width и он создает это белое пространство. В качестве костыля не видя кода могу вам предложить только поставить html, body {overflow-x:hidden} Но лучше найдите блок с заданой шириной.

Comment: @TheDrote тоже думал просто запретить скролл вбок, но спокойно же можно отдалить экран на телефоне и все равно будет виден данный блок, хорошо, как доберусь до кода, обязательно еще раз все перечитаю и пересмотрю, а после если что выложу. Спасибо!

Comment: Это код всей вашей страницы?

Comment: @E_K нет конечно) Это часть кода, и как и другие части они вот такое делают в моб.версии

Comment: @AntonBrock, Включайте DevTools  и проверяйте каждый блок, у вас скорее всего где-то контент не влазит.

Comment: @E_K да, вы и выше человек были правы, не заметил что нижний контент ушел вбок (как?) , но проблему решил! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В css добавить .b1{margin:0px auto!important;padding:0px!important;}

Comment: Окей! Я понял что ты хотел сказать этим. Возьму на заметку, но проблема была в вылезающем блоке (да-да, он типа тикой, нененене буду игнорировать твои стили)